# Relative path for related projects in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, relative-path

I have a project which is dependent on a library created from another project. While this runs in netbeans for my desktop, it does not, when i build it remotely because the related project(which i add using the properties tab, in Linker->Libraries) with the library is added with the absolute path! Is there a way to add this with relative path?

Answer (score 0):

While, I have not found a proper solution to this problem, currently I am manually moving the library to the path where it is required to be, by the main project in the remote computer.